Allowing accounts.google.com in WordPress Playground
I am trying to use GA4 plugins on WordPress Playground. When I authenticate them to the GA4 account, the request is blocked showing the following:
accounts.google.com is blocked
accounts.google.com refused to connect.

ERR_BLOCKED_BY_RESPONSE

I am using the Blueprints API to create a playground instance using JSON format. I have tried creating a JSON Key file from Google Cloud Console > IAM & Admin, but I can't figure out how to incorporate this into Blueprint.
How can I allow the request to proceed so I can authenticate the plugin(s) to the GA4 account?

This question might better be answered by the people behind WordPress Playground. Odds are this is something to do with WordPress Playground most likely a web server config issue. I'm pretty sure this isn't a WordPress thing. Either way, I'd need a lot more details to so much as Google for an answer.
